# Rocket in constant gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

A Rocket in a constant gravitational field, what are the conditions required for the rocket to take off immediately? (in terms of $m_0,μ,g,v_r$), where

$m_0$ = mass of the rocket at $t=0$

$μ$ = mass per unit time of expelled gas;

$v_r$ = velocity of the expelled gas relative to the rocket

Show that, in this case, the velocity of the rocket always grows (until the fuel is used up).

If this condition is not fulfilled, then there are two possibilities: Either the velocity is always descending, or there is a moment in time when the velocity, after descending, starts to grow again. Find the condition separating these two cases (will involve the mass $m_1$ of the rocket without fuel).

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a condition that ensures that the rocket immediately takes off?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158979/)

Comment: @Jim Well the answers there wasn't clear enough.. but thanks for the help.

Comment: The fact that the answers weren't clear for you does not mean it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I wonder if @rndflas is in the same class as [this guy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158979/how-to-find-a-condition-that-ensures-that-the-rocket-immediately-takes-off).  Must be tonight's homework.

Comment: @Brionius I'm pretty much sure we are in same class, but dont know who exactly... Anyways thanks for the answer!